# Can not read property of undefined at datatable

Tags: typescript, angular6, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to conditionally style the primeng datatable row background color. I used `[rowStyleClass]="setBackgroundColor"` where `setBackgroundColor` is a function that conditionally returns the name of class to be applied. but while I'm checking the property of a variable of the class. the property is said to be undefined.

I declared a global variable name `requisition` within the class like

`requisition: CreateRequisitionFromPreRequisitionInput;`

then I initialized it within the constructor like

`this.requisition = new CreateRequisitionFromPreRequisitionInput();`

the variable `requisition` has a property name `requisitionDate`. but when I try to access the variable within the function it said that the property as well the variable is also undefined. but when I log the variable within the `ngAfterContentInit()` function or any other function it logs the variable. just within the `setBackgroundColor` function does not access it.

`

```
setBackgroundColor(rowData: any, rowIndex: number) {
    return rowData.preRequisitionDate > this.requisition.requisitionDate ?  'backColor-red' : null;
}
```

`

here the property requsitionDate is sade to be undefined though I initialized the variable within the constructor.

Comment: How are you getting the data that determines if setBackgroundColor is true?

Is this process asynchronous like a http call? If it is, that value may not be available when your table loads.

Comment: No I don't get the value from any http call. here I'm declearing a variable of type `CreateRequisitionFromPreRequisitionInput` which is an input dto in backend .I am using asp.net core in back end. so the input dto type alredy loaded in front end because I updated service proxy. and the value is binding with the variable is from user input

Comment: the variable is available all over the class except the setBackgroundColor function.

Comment: Well, I think you are going to need to step through it to see what the values are at runtime. Are you using MS Code?

Comment: no, I am using VS Code

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: that does not help much. I did not understand the process clearly

Comment: If you are checking the values of a property at some point in the page load life cycle and its not null/undefined, but it is when you are calling the function, then I would suggest you would need to step through the page ngOnInit and check the value there. You say that the data for the page isn't coming from an async source, which means its either in a data cache or a model is being passed to it.